# Is it possible that probability of occuring intersection of two events will be greater than probability of occuring each of them?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference

If $A$ and $B$ are correlated events, Is it possible that we have :
$$P\left(A \cap B \right) \geq P\left( A\right)$$
and
$$P\left(A \cap B \right) \geq P\left( B\right)$$
Is it possible?

Comment: In regards to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2955535/27978, it is a bit annoying to waste time answering questions for someone to have them delete the question. I like to help people, but when you delete the question, no one else can benefit from the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general $(A \cap B) \subseteq A$ so $P\left(A \cap B \right) \leq P\left( A\right)$

So you can only have $P\left(A \cap B \right) \geq P\left( A\right)$ when $P\left(A \cap B \right) = P\left( A\right)$ and that only happens when $P(A \cap B^c)=0$, an example of which is $A \subseteq B$

Similarly you can only have $P\left(A \cap B \right) \geq P\left( B\right)$ when $P\left(A \cap B \right) = P\left( B\right)$ and that only happens when $P(A^c \cap B)=0$, an example of which is $B \subseteq A$

So the simplest example is when $A=B$ and all examples will have the difference (*exclusive or*) between $A$ and $B$ has zero probability where you get $P\left(A \cap B \right) = P\left( A\right) = P\left( B\right)$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $A=B$, then $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B) = \mathbb{P}(A)=\mathbb{P}(B)$.

Now observe that we have $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B) = \mathbb{P}(A\setminus (B^c\cap A)) = \mathbb{P}(A) - \mathbb{P}(B^c \cap A)$ so your statement can only be true if $A\subseteq B$ almost surely. If you must satisfy the two, then you have also $B\subseteq A$ almost surely which means the two are equals almost surely.

Comment: I don't mean in general conditions. I meant is there any specific conditions that the statement will be true?

Comment: Well, then $A\subseteq B$ a.s. for the first one and $B\subseteq A$ a.s. for the second one. This is because $\mathbb{P}(B^c\cap A) = 0$ which means $B^c \cap A = \emptyset$ a.s and this means $A\subseteq B$ a.s.